# Extract the formula for stepwise optimized regression model

Tags: r, model, regression, linear-regression

I performed a multiple linear regression. My real dataframe contains a lot of more x-values.

```
Regression <- lm(df1$y ~ df2$x1 + df2$x2 + df2$x3 + df2$x4 + df2$x5 + df2$x6)

StepRegression=step(Regression,direction="both")

#Or with the MASS package
library(MASS)
step.model <- stepAIC(Regression, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)
step.model
```

My question is now, how do I automatically get the optimized model? I tired this:

```
library(MASS)
OptiRegression = step.model$call
```

But this only gives me this:

```
lm(formula =df1$y ~ df2$x1 + df2$x3 + df2$x5)

summary(test)
Length  Class   Mode 
     2   call   call
```

But I want to get the summary of the updated model, with the coefficients which I get for example when I typ in:

```
OptiRegression = lm(df1$y ~ df2$x1 + df2$x3 + df2$x5)
summary (OptiRegression)
```

Comment: Check out `str(step.model$terms)`.

Comment: Thanks, so is it $formula? But how can I use it? step.model$formula doesnt work.

Comment: I also read about $anova, but I am still not able to get it working.

Comment: I don't understand, what doesn't work? The `step` and `stepAIC` functions already return the updated model. You don't have to do what you are doing with `OptiRegression`. Anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do something like any of the following two regressions. I will use the built-in dataset `mtcars` since you have not posted one.

```
library(MASS)

Regression <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

StepRegression <- step(Regression, direction = "both")

OptiReg1 <-StepRegression$terms
fit1 <- lm(OptiReg1, data = mtcars)
```

As you can see, both summaries are equal, only the formula changes.

```
summary(StepRegression)
summary(fit1)
```

Or with the `MASS` package, function `stepAIC`.

```
step.model <- stepAIC(Regression, direction = "both", trace = FALSE)

OptiReg2 <- step.model$terms
fit2 <- lm(OptiReg2, mtcars)
```

Now, once again, these two summaries are in practice equal, only the formula changes. And it changes because in `fit2` what is passed is `OptiReg`.

```
summary(step.model)
summary(fit2)
```